# Does minimal degree $n$ imply a $K_n$ minor

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-minors

Is it true that any finite graph has a $K_n$ minor, where $n$ is a minimal vertex degree?

Comment: Not if the graph is infinite (e.g. $n=3$ and the infinite binary tree).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*No.*

The [edge-graph of the icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Icosahedral_graph) is regular of degree five, but does not have a $K_5$ minor because it is planar ([Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)).

Comment: This is a great (counter)example.

Comment: Also the smallest if I am not mistaken. No $K_4$-minor means the graph has a vertex of degree 2.

Answer (score 22):

More generally, it is a classic result (independently due to Kostochka and Thomason) that minimum degree $(\alpha+o(1))n \sqrt{\log n}$ suffices to force a $K_n$ minor, where $\alpha$ is an explicit constant.  Conversely, there are random graphs with minimum degree $\Omega(n\sqrt{\log n})$ that do not contain a $K_n$ minor.   See [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82620335.pdf) to access the paper by Thomason.

**Update.** [Alon, Krivelevich, and Sudakov](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08530) have recently given a new short proof of the Kostochka-Thomason result.

Comment: Where can I read about this in detail?

Comment: I added a link to the corresponding paper by Thomason.  Note that Thomason's result is stated for average degree, but every graph with average degree $d$ contains a subgraph of minimum degree $\frac{d}{2}$.